# good design pattern for multifaceted iterator?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator

[Apologies if this question seems opinionated or discussionworthy.]

I have a class which, although not a collection class per se, does contain an arbitrary number of elements which are primarily constructed via an 'append' method:

```
append(TypeA thingA, TypeB thingB, TypeC thingC);
```

Significantly, there is *not* an auxiliary struct or class anywhere tying together a triple of (`thingA`, `thingB`, `thingC`), nor has one been needed so far -- the class works fine as-is.

Today I decided I needed an iterator for this class, that could return all the things I'd added to it, almost as if it were a collection, after all.  The question is, what's the best way to return `thingA`, `thingB`, and `thingC`?

I *could* belatedly define an auxiliary tuple struct, just so that the iterator could return instances of it.  But this seemed a little odd.

What I implemented instead was something along the lines of

```
class FunnyCollectionIter {
    FunnyCollection* _ctx;
    unsigned int _i;

  public:
    FunnyCollectionIter();

    const TypeA& thingA() const;
    const TypeB& thingB() const;
    const TypeC& thingC() const;

    FunnyCollectionIter& operator=(const FunnyCollectionIter &rhs);
    FunnyCollectionIter& operator++();
    bool operator==(const FunnyCollectionIter &rhs) const;
    // ...
    }
};
```

And I'm using it with code like this:

```
FunnyCollectionIter it;
for(it = funnycollection.begin(); it != funnycollection.end(); ++it) {
    // now do things with it.thingA(), it.thingB(), and it.thingC()        
 }
```

But this seems a little odd, too.  Normally (in the STL, at least) you access an iterator either using `*`, or `->first` and `->second`.  But in the scheme I've implemented, there's no `*`, no `->`, no `first` and `second` (let alone `third`?), and the interesting names `thingA`, `thingB`, and `thingC` are methods to invoke, not members to access.

So my question is, is this a poor way to construct an iterator in this situation, and is there a better way?

If it helps, the class is actually a scheduler.  The three "things" in question are a duration, a callback, and an optional name.  The caller constructs a schedule via one or more calls to `append()`, and then normally the schedule just runs, but now I have a need for the caller to be able to review the just-constructed schedule.  (This is the same class I was referring to in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879245/sigc-unbind-or-deconstruct-a-functor).)

Comment: *So my question is, is this a poor way to construct an iterator in this situation, and is there a better way?* I'm leaning towards yes and IDK without seeing how this collection is actually implemented.

Comment: @NathanOliver Added a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

You might split your class to have iterator interface on one side, and specific interface on the other side:

```
class FunnyWrapper
{
    FunnyCollection* _ctx;
    unsigned int _i;
public:
    const TypeA& thingA() const;
    const TypeB& thingB() const;
    const TypeC& thingC() const;

    // ...

    // trick to use operator -> in iterator.
    FunnyWrapper* operator ->() { return this; }
};

class FunnyCollectionIter
{
    FunnyCollection* _ctx;
    unsigned int _i;

  public:
    FunnyCollectionIter();

    FunnyCollectionIter& operator=(const FunnyCollectionIter &rhs);
    FunnyCollectionIter& operator++();
    bool operator==(const FunnyCollectionIter &rhs) const;
    // ...

    FunnyWrapper operator->() { return FunnyWrapper{_ctx, _i}; }
    FunnyWrapper operator*() { return FunnyWrapper{_ctx, _i}; }
};
```